# Google drive integration

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

We are building a web application that should get all files from a specific folder in our Drive (read only). The problem is that I can't find a way to access our files without using OAuth. Basically I would want to request our files using AJAX and present the contents of them on a page (without the user having to do anything). Is this at all possible and have I missed something?

Whenever I try something without using OAuth I get a global internalError (being related to authorization according to the current documentation).

The experience I'm trying to achieve:

User enters http://domain.com/posts > Get all public files from folder Y > Sort them by date > Show the titles in HTML > User clicks title > User is presented with full contents of the file as HTML.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance! :)

UPDATE: To clarify: I would want to depend on our API key only.

Comment: I think you will have to use authentication

Comment: But i dont want any user end authentication

Comment: There is no way you can acess drive api or any other google api without oauth 2.0 authentication.

Comment: Can a service account be used to access folder in my google drive??